# Can't run executable file on Ubuntu, terminal expects sudo, or gives errors like “Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character”

Tags: compiling, executable

I'm trying to run executable files on Ubuntu, but it's not working, although the exact same executable file works fine on others' machines, which are also running Ubuntu 12.04 like me. Based on this, I asked a question here: [Executing compiled file on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940763/executing-compiled-file-on-ubuntu-invalid-or-incomplete-multibyte-or-wide-char)

But now I realize the issue isn't in my compiled file.
Because I wrote a very simple .cpp file and tested it, but Ubuntu still didn't run it.

This is my simple test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
 printf ("Hello, this test worked!");
return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled it:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o test test.cpp
```

And then tried to run it:

```
./test
```

But I get an error:

```
bash: ./test: Permission denied
```

So I try with sudo:

sudo ./test

which asks me for my user password, which I give, but then it says:

```
sudo: ./test: command not found
```

So how can I run executable files at all?

### Edit

I've got this Ubuntu installed on top of Windows, using the Wubi installer.

When I run:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

I get this:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
```

When I run

```
df .
```

It says:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      17596475 6112377  11484098  35% /
```

And when I run:

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

Then this is the output:

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=1944900k,nr_inodes=486225,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=781788k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sda4 /host fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/loop0 / ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/asaaki/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
```

Comment: What does `ls -l test` say?

Comment: It says: **-rw------- 1 asaaki asaaki 8380 Apr  8 18:16 test** . "asaaki" is the user, me. But this is after I've already run: **sudo chmod -x test** and  **sudo chmod 755 test**.

Comment: What does `umask` say?

Comment: How do I use umask? I ran *umask* and I got *0002*

Comment: Your umask looks ok.  `chmod -x` removes the executable permission.  You'd do `chmod +x` to add it.

Comment: I did this: First I did **chmod +x test**, then I did **./test**, but it still said **permission denied**.

Comment: What is the path to `test`? From what you say above, it seems like you've put it on a filesystem mounted with the `noexec` option (which will be the default for filesystems mounted with the `user` option, often used for removable media such as USBs.

Comment: Well, I've installed Ubuntu using wubi, the Windows installer. The path to test is: **/media/060489018SDF/opencv/build/include**, where *06048....* is a long string that refers to the C: drive on my Windows 7. It's either */media* or */home/media*... can't remember exactly right now because I'm on Windows again.

Comment: What's the output of `pkg-config --cflags opencv`? What filesystem are you doing this on: the Linux filesystem, or a Windows filesystem? Post the output of `df .` and `cat /proc/mounts`.

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu on a Windows system. I've edited my question to include the output of the commands you've mentioned.

Comment: Is there really no solution then?

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you compiling it wrong? Shouldn't it be like:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o test.cpp test
```

or

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` test.cpp -o  test
```

Comment: It certainly shouldn't be like your first suggestion; that would try to compile a file called `test` (the intended output) and store the result in a file called `test.cpp` (the intended input).